# _GET in PHP for variable with multiple values

Tags: php, variables, get

I am sending a variable with multiple values like this:

JQUERY:

```
 $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?color=' + colors.join("+"), function()
```

-->
    indexMain.php?colors=blue+red+brown

I want to _GET those values and then use them in a while loop to put them into a SQL query like this one:

```
$items = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = :colorbase1");
$items -> bindValue(":colorbase1", $color);
```

Thanks!

EDIT: here is my current code but it is not working, it just shows the items corresponding to the 1st color.

```
foreach (explode(' ', $_GET['color']) as $color) 
    {
        $items = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = :colorbase1");
        $items -> bindValue(":colorbase1", $color);

    }
```

Comment: That parameter only has a single value, "blue red brown".

Comment: You can't bind more than one value to one "variable" in PDO.

Comment: @Tyler, he said that he wanted to use them in a while loop, so I am guessing that he intends to use them one at a time. I could be wrong though :-P.

Comment: What does `var_dump(explode(' ', $_GET['color']));` output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
indexMain.php?color=blue+red+brown
```

should be

```
indexMain.php?colors%5B%5D=blue&colors%5B%5D=red&colors%5B%5D=brown
```

which is equivalent to

```
indexMain.php?colors[]=blue&colors[]=red&colors[]=brown
```

This creates an array accessible with `$_GET['colors']`. After that use this PHP:

```
foreach ($_GET['colors'] as $color) {
    $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = :colorbase1");
    if ($query->execute(":colorbase1", $color)) {
        // use results from query
    } else {
        // handle failed query
    }
}
```

If you don't want to change the query string, you can do this alternatively:

```
foreach (explode(' ', $_GET['colors']) as $color) {
    $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = :colorbase1");
    if ($query->execute(":colorbase1", $color)) {
        // use results from query
    } else {
        // handle failed query
    }
}
```

Note that the only change is in the first line and we are splitting the string by spaces (because "+" gets converted to a space character).

Also note that both examples assume that `$_GET['colors']` is defined. You can use `isset()` to check if it is defined.

Comment: Hi, thanks this looks good but doesn't work in my code... I am editing my original post with the current code... Thanks!

Comment: Well, you're not using the code that I provided. You're binding a variable but not doing anything with it. You have to execute the query like I did.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
$colors = explode(' ', $_GET['color']);
foreach($colors as $color) {
    // your code here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my code on the top following your idea but it doesn't work yet... would you mind taking a look? It's edited

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$colors = explode("+", $_GET['color']);
foreach($colors as $color){
$items = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = :colorbase1");
$items -> bindValue(":colorbase1", $color);
}
```

How about this

```
$colors = explode(" ", $_GET['color']);
foreach($colors as $color){
$items = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = :colorbase1");
$items -> bindValue(":colorbase1", $color);
}
```

Comment: wouldn't `+` in a query parameter be converted to spaces?

Comment: This will not work, $_GET['color'] will contain spaces, not the '+' sign that the GET parameter would have been encoded with.

Comment: @EvanTeran please check the latter one . .

Comment: @Geoffrey please check the latter one . .